# Query Creation Does Not Print All Indexes

Tags: java, apache-poi

When I create the file and write in the query, does it write only once? why?

```
for (spinelliIndex = 0; spinelliIndex < spinelli.getVeicoli_id().size(); spinelliIndex++) {
            boolean match = false;
            for (veicoloIndex = 0; veicoloIndex < veicoloDb.getVeicoloId().size(); veicoloIndex++) {
                if (spinelli.getVeicoli_targa().get(spinelliIndex).equals(veicoloDb.getTarga().get(veicoloIndex))) {
                    match = true;

                    // Stampa a Video
                    System.out.println(spinelli.getVeicoli_targa().get(spinelliIndex) + " = "
                            + veicoloDb.getTarga().get(veicoloIndex) + " --> "
                            + spinelli.getVeicoli_id().get(spinelliIndex) + " --> "
                            + veicoloDb.getVeicoloId().get(veicoloIndex));

                    // Scrivi nella riga i
                    row = sheet.getRow(spinelliIndex);

                    // Scrivi nella colonna AC indice 28
                    cell = row.createCell(28);

                    // Scrivi il ciclo in tutte le righe nella colonna AC indice 28
                    sheet.getRow(spinelliIndex).createCell(28)
                            .setCellValue(spinelli.getVeicoli_id().get(spinelliIndex));

                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath);

                    // Scrivi nel file EXCEL
                    wb.write(fos);
                    fos.close();

                    // Scrivi NEl file .txt
                    // Crea la Query e scrivi nel file
                    file = new File(path);
                    fw = new FileWriter(file);

                    fw.write("UPDATE veicolo SET ID = " + "'" + spinelli.getVeicolo_newid().get(spinelliIndex) + "'" + ","
                            + "CREATE_DATE = " + "'" + veicoloDb.getCreate_date().get(veicoloIndex) + "'" + ","
                            + "MODIFIED_DATE = " + "'" + veicoloDb.getModified_date().get(veicoloIndex) + "'" + "," + "UUID = "
                            + "'" + veicoloDb.getUuid().get(veicoloIndex) + "'" + "," + "CLASSE_EURO = " + "'"
                            + veicoloDb.getClasse_euro().get(veicoloIndex) + "'" + "," + "CODICE_CLIENTE_ORIGINARIO = " + "'"
                            + veicoloDb.getCodice_cliente_originario().get(veicoloIndex) + "'" + "," + "CONTRATTO = " + "'"
                            + veicoloDb.getContratto().get(veicoloIndex) + "'" + "," + "DATA_FINE_VALIDITA = " + "'"
                            + veicoloDb.getData_fine_validita().get(veicoloIndex) + "'" + "," + "DATA_INIZIO_VALIDITA = " + "'"
                            + veicoloDb.getData_inizio_validita().get(veicoloIndex) + "'" + "," + "DISPONIBILITA = " + "'"
                            + veicoloDb.getDisponibilita().get(veicoloIndex) + "'" + "," + "NAZIONE = " + "'"
                            + veicoloDb.getNazione().get(veicoloIndex) + "'" + "," + "TARGA = " + "'" + veicoloDb.getTarga().get(veicoloIndex)
                            + "'" + "," + "TIPO_DI_POSSESSO = " + "'" + veicoloDb.getTipo_di_possesso().get(veicoloIndex) + "'"
                            + "," + "ID_ANAGRAFICA = " + "'" + veicoloDb.getId_anagrafica().get(veicoloIndex) + "'"
                            + "FROM DISPOSITIVO_VEICOLO WHERE dispositivo_veicolo.id_anagrafica = veicolo.id_anagrafica"
                            + ";" + "\n");
                    fw.flush();

                    fw.close();

                }

            }
            // Targhe non trovate
            if (!match) {
                System.out.println("Targa non trovata: " + spinelli.getVeicoli_targa().get(spinelliIndex));
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is your expected behavior on your program, but I guess you want to write(append) your file multiple times, right?

In your code, create new file (`new File()`) and close the writer (`fw.close()`) in the loop.
It looks, the program overwrite to the same file multiple times.

So, if you want to append(not overwrite), I recommend you to put file creation and file closing on the outside of the loop like the following (dummy code):

```
file = new File(path);
fw = new FileWriter(file);
for (spinelliIndex = 0; spinelliIndex < spinelli.getVeicoli_id().size(); spinelliIndex++) {
    fw.write("something");
}
fw.close();
```

Also, `fw.close()` will call `fw.flush()`. If you don't have any specific reason to write it, you can remove it.